# Is 'what to do' a clause?

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses, infinitive-clauses

> *I don't know **what to do**.*

Here, is ***what to do*** a clause?

If so, what's the reasoning for that?

Comment: Yes. It's an interrogative infinitival clause functioning as complement of "know".

Comment: Excuse me for what must seem a silly question, but why is it important to know whether "what to do" is a clause or not? What do you hope to learn from answers? What do *you* say it is?

Comment: @Mari-LouA If it had to be a clause, then a VP headed by a non-finite verb should be treated as a clause, I think.

Comment: "had to be"?  As in, someone in the past said there was no other choice?

Comment: *a verb phrase headed by a non-finite verb should be treated as a clause* What do you mean? Is someone saying that "what to do" is not a clause. And if they are, why does it matter? If you consider it a clause, and you want it confirmed then that is what you should ask.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'll tell you why it's important to know whether 'what to do' is a clause or not. If it's a clause, then that means that you should treat a verb phrase headed by a non-finite verb as a clause even without any subject present.

Comment: "what to do" is the direct object of: I don't know and a relative clause.

Answer (score 1):

"what to do" is definitely a clause. Because "to do" is an infinitive relative clause; an example of an infinitive relative clause (according to this [Random Idea English blog post](http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/11/relative-infinitive-clauses-uses-and.html)) is:

> *Jenny is definitely somebody to keep an eye on.*
> (= somebody who you should keep an eye on)

Therefore, "I know what to do," meaning, "I know what I should do," is simply structured as "what + an infinitive relative clause.

Comment: FYI, Alexnormin might believe that "what to do" is "definitely" a clause (various people might call it an infinitive relative clause, reduced relative clause, etc.), but that opinion is not universal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

Clause is a part of sentence that has a subject & a predicate yet doesn't make complete sense (like a sentence).

In 'what to do' alone, 'what' is an interrogative pronoun that acts as the subject.

Therefore 'what to do' is a clause.

Comment: an independent clause makes complete sense as a sentenced. Most main clauses work as separate sentences.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence

> I don't know **what to do**.

**what to do** is not a clause because it does not have a verb (except an infinitive).

An example where **what (something)** is a clause is:

> I don't know **what** time it **is**.

In this second example, we have the verb **is** which makes **what time it is** a clause.

---

So what is **"what to do"**? It is definitely a phrase. However, I am not an expert in English language theory, and I cannot guarantee the correctness of my answer below.

Comparing:

> - I don't know **what to do**.
> - I don't know **anything**.
> - I don't know **my weight**.

then **"what to do"** could be a (pro)noun phrase.

Answer (score -2):

"What to do" is not a clause.  It is, with the verb, the sentence predicate and the object of the sentence.  Let's use a simpler sentence.

> I know that.

Subject: I
Verb: know
Object: that

Thus, from your example:

Subject: I
Verb: do not know
Object: what to do

You may be confused because the phrases "I know" and "I don't know" are frequently used to answer questions.  They're colloquialisms and not complete sentences (lacking an object).  Please remember that clauses can be removed from their sentences and what's left behind remains a complete sentence.  Thus,

> I know what to do because John taught me.

The phrase "because John taught me" is a clause.  When removed, you're left with the complete sentence, "I know what to do."

Comment: If you think 'what to do' is not a clause, I suggest you should at least tell me what you think it really is. Do you think it's a noun phrase? OR something else?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  You could describe a clause as a compound adjective or a compound adverb, but the role it plays in the sentence is that of "clause."  In specific, the interrogative pronoun "what" is the direct object of the infinitive "to do."  You could describe the phrase as a compound pronoun, but the role it plays in the sentence is that of "object."  That is what it really is.

Comment: I don't understand this: "Please remember that clauses can be removed from their sentences and what's left behind remains a complete sentence." IF this is true, what about _I don't know what I should do._? Here, _what I should do_ is definitely a clause. But according to your logic, removing it only leaves 'I don't know', which you somehow argue is not a complete sentence.

Comment: Why do you believe it is a clause?  The object of the sentence is still the word "what."  Adding an auxilliary verb to the infinitive doesn't transform the predicate.

Comment: Then, consider this sentence instead: _I know you're mistaken._ Here, _you're mistaken_ is clearly a clause, right? Then, removing it leaves only _I know_, which you yourself said is not a complete sentence. What gives?

Comment: "because John taught me" in a phrase because it's headed by a preposition *because*.

Comment: Your example is not grammatically perfect.  It should read, "I know that you are mistaken."  It is very common in English to drop the "that," but it's important to this discussion.  When properly using the conjunctive "that" you have what is known as a "that" clause that creates a compound sentence.  Dropping the clause leaves you with the complete sentence "I know that."  So, you do have a clause, you just didn't write the sentence using formal rules.